# Creating multiple log instances using log4j to output log files in separate locations

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am writing a multi-threaded application in which I need a log file output for each thread using log4j. Ideally, I would like to have a separate log instance running for each thread. I am debating as to how I should tackle this. Because the location of the file output is different for each log instance, I need to update the `log4j.appender.BrokerFile.File=` property for each instance. As of right now I am trying to create a new Logger, set the new properties into a properties object, and load the new properties into my newly created Logger object using `PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProperties);` While the new Logger instance is being created just fine, the new properties do not seem to be recognized by the new instance. Do I need to create a new FileAppender for each new Logger instance?

```
public class Broker implements Runnable{

    private Settings ss; //The Settings object associated with this broker.

    private String loggerName = null;
    private Logger log = null;
    private Properties log4jProperties = new Properties();
}

    //Constructor
    public Broker(Settings ss){

        this.ss = ss;
    }

    public void run() {

        loggerName = ss.getBrokerName() + "_Logger";
        log = Logger.getLogger(loggerName);

        log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.loggerName", "DEBUG, FILE");
            log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE","org.apache.log4j.FileAppender");
            log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.File", "C:/Logz/"+loggerName+".out");
            log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush", "true");
            log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold", "DEBUG");
            log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.Append", "FALSE");
            log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.layout", "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
            log4jProperties.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern", "%m%n");

            PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProperties);

            log.debug("This is a debug message");


            // This will be set to true as long as the Broker is running
            while(isRunnable){

                //Listen for and process files      

            }
    }
```

Here is the console output. As you can see the new logger instances are being created but the new properties are not being recognized.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Broker1_Logger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Broker2_Logger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Broker3_Logger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

This goes on for every broker. Is there any way to directly apply my configuration settings to the Logger object? For example, something like 
    **log**.PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jproperties);
There must be a way to apply the configuration settings to each logger object created.

Thank You,

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that creating a new appender for each new instance is necessary, since each instance needs to print to a different file output location. I solved this problem by creating a generateLogger() method with the necessary parameters to create new loggers and appenders programmitcally. If you will notice the first parameter contains the name of a parent logger. If I include this in my new logger name, it will inherit the properties of its parent, which is configured in my master.properties file, and vice versa. For example, if my parent logger is "Broker" and my logger name is "Broker1", then the full loggerName will be "Broker.Broker1". This way I can track all the brokers in one log file while also having separate log files for each broker in their own separate file output locations. Not to mention, this method can be re-used with many different kinds of Logs using different parent loggers. Though the parent Logger is not even necessary if you choose. If you choose to not have a parent Logger, simply delete it from the method and disregard my master.properties file.

```
public Logger generateLogger(String parent, String name, String logDirectory, String filePattern, String fileThreshold) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Create Logger 
            String loggerName = parent + "." + name;
            Logger log = Logger.getLogger(loggerName);


            //Create Logging File Appender
            RollingFileAppender fileApp = new RollingFileAppender();
            fileApp.setName("Broker." + loggerName + "_FileAppender");
            fileApp.setFile(logDirectory +"/"+ name+".log");
            fileApp.setLayout(new PatternLayout(filePattern));
            fileApp.setThreshold(Level.toLevel(fileThreshold));
            fileApp.setAppend(true);
            fileApp.activateOptions();

            log.addAppender(fileApp);


            return log;     
}
```

Here is the Broker logger configuration inside my master.properties file for reference.

```
log4j.logger.Broker=DEBUG, BrokerFile

    # Broker Appenders
    # Broker File Appender
        log4j.appender.BrokerFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
        log4j.appender.BrokerFile.File=C:/Documents and Settings/gr2cher/My Documents/KTLO/Java/CMInbound/BrokerLogs/Logs/Broker.log
        log4j.appender.BrokerFile.MaxFileSize=1MB
        log4j.appender.BrokerFile.MaxBackupIndex=1
        log4j.appender.BrokerFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
        log4j.appender.BrokerFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
        log4j.appender.BrokerFile.threshold=DEBUG
```